# Parallel Random Number Generators

Tags: c#, .net, random

I would like to know whether there is any random number generator which can generate random numbers in parallel such that the generated sequences should not have dependency in between them.

To be specific, if i have two tasks and each tasks generate random numbers, then there must be no dependency and no overlap.

Comment: **then there must be no dependency and no overlap.** -> what does **no overlap** mean in this case?

Comment: no overlap means numbers generated in one series must not be the same in the other series generated in parallel.

dependency may be anything ( like seed, or any factor).

Answer (score 2):

The `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class should meet your needs.

It's designed to be less deterministic than `System.Random`, and is also thread-safe.

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out this post: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx

Comment: thanks Tallek. It does create thread safe thread local random numbers.

But my next question is whether the random numbers generated by each thread have any correlation ? 

What are the chances of Numbers generated by one thread overlapping on the numbers from another thread ?

Comment: If you create two PRNGs and use a different seed, their output is more or less non-correlated. Because its probably difficult to say "no correlation" if you have a deterministic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this article about generating random numbers in parallel:

[Getting random numbers in a thread-safe way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx)

it helped me with the same problem some time ago.